# JQuery hover loop

Tags: jquery, css, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a problem with this JQuery code:

```
$(".item").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("item");
    $(".item").hide(700);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).addClass("item");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(".item").show(700);
});
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
</ul>
```

I want when I do hover on one item, other items be hide, the code works fine but the problem is there if I hover another item in duration of hiding (700 ms), it will make a loop of hide/show items. what can I do for prevent this.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/7vQ4b/1/)

*note: I want the hovered item goes to left, not stay fixed.*

Comment: bad UI concept simply because you can't avoid hovering another due to floats. As they animate they shift positions. WOuld animating opacity work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using `float: left` to the `li` elements.. so the `ul` was with no width and height. Apply this CSS:

```
ul {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and also I made some changes in jQuery:

```
$(".item").on('mouseenter', mEnter)
$('ul').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.item').stop();
    $('.active').removeClass("active")
        .addClass("item");
    $(".item").show(700);
});

function mEnter() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("item");
    $(".item").hide(700);
}
```

you were applying `mouseleave` event to the individual hovered `LI` element instead of the parent element i.e `UL`.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vQ4b/4/)

Comment: Nicely done...  this seems to work just as the OP is intending.

Comment: btw, no need of wrapping in a function.. I just did it while testing.